# V\B Script to extract date from a text file and format it

Tags: date, vbscript, extract, date-formatting

I work on OCR. We extract text from invoices automatically. When the contents of the invoice are extracted they are stored in a text file, and then we write scripts to extract the data from the text file according to our requirements. 
One requirement that has got me stuck is, i need to extract the date from a text file which is not written in any particular format. Its written as 12 08 2014 in a line. I need to extract this and print it out in the dd/mm/yyyy format. 
Also, the dates can be written in any format, for example 2nd December 2013, 12-12-2013, 12 Aug 2013 and so on...I need to read the date and extract it in the form of dd/mm/yyyy

```
ORDERED SHIPPED 

THE DATE IS IN THE NEXT LINE 28 08 14, I NEED TO EXTRACT THIS AND PRINT IT IN THE DD/MM/YYYY FORMAT 
01239751 **28 08 14** 03 09 14 E31192-00 1 
CUST.NO. ItN1 R 0 R NO SALE MM 
NOM CI WATT VOTRF NO nr CAMMANOF in-W.01M 
ADDRESS HERE**strong text**
Te1:(123)123-1234/ Fax:(123)795-1234
Facture / Invoice 
OUTPS:R-103958989 CONE:MONS Taws> NET 60 DAYS 
SOLD TO / VENDU A SHIPPED TO / EXPEDIE A
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try assigning to a date. Date functions recognise most dates.

Comment: The problem i have is that thr is no pre defind spot in the document, it can be anywhere in the text file. As far as a fixed text goes, again its not constant. Sometimes the date is after the invoice number sometimes its after the description. The date can be in the top or middle or at the bottom. It all depends on the format of the invoice. The data is just extracted from the invoce and saved in a text file from where we have to recover the required fields. Is there any way to genreally locate the date from a text file without any fixed help from any other fields, keywords etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need a plan based on an idea. My idea is to apply a set of pairs of a regular expression (to cut a date representation from your data) and a conversion function (to make a date out of that cut).

In code:

```
Option Explicit

' 12-12-2013
Function DMY(oMT)
  DMY = DateSerial(CInt(oMT.SubMatches(2)), CInt(oMT.SubMatches(1)), CInt(oMT.SubMatches(0)))
End Function

' CDate will reliably convert the extracted value
Function TrustCDate(oMT)
  TrustCDate = CDate(oMT.Value)
End Function

' 12-12-2013
Dim reDMY : Set reDMY = New RegExp
reDMY.Global  = True
reDMY.Pattern = "(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})"

' collection of re, func pairs
Dim aOps : aOps = Array( _
      Array(reDMY, GetRef("DMY")) _
    , Array(reDMY, GetRef("TrustCDate")) _
)

Dim sAll : sAll = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(".\25986937.txt").ReadAll()
Dim aOp
For Each aOp In aOps
    Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = aOp(0).Execute(sAll)
    If 1 = oMTS.Count Then
       Dim dtCut : dtCut = aOp(1)(oMTS(0))
       WScript.Echo TypeName(dtCut), dtCut
    End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 25986937.vbs
Date 12.11.2014
Date 11.12.2014
```

for a file that starts with:

```
ORDERED SHIPPED

01239751 12-11-2014 03 09 14 E31192-00 1
CUST.NO. ItN1 R 0 R NO SALE MM
```

By adding/improving RegExps (will your OCR sometimes deliver O (capital letter o) instead of (digit) 0?) and conversion functions (in which cases can you trust CDate?) you should be able to handle most of your input and to identify the cases in which a human being has to deal with freaks.

Comment: However there is another problem now. In some of the invoices we have the date written as 1/6/2014. The porblem is we do not know the format here. 1 can be the month or 1 can be the day. We have to extract it and print it out in the dd/mm/yyyy format. Is there a way to understand the format that we have got it in?

Comment: Date 1/6/2014                                                        How do i understand which feild is the day and which is the month. 1 can be day or the month, is there a way of understanding that.

Comment: I am not able to run the code as well, can you please guide me.

Comment: any further ideas..??